# Construction of field extension for $[E:\mathbb F_{11}]=3$

Tags: proof-verification, field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

> Let $\mathbb F_{11}\subset E$. Construct a field extension $E$ of $\Bbb{F}_{11}$ such that $[E:\mathbb F_{11}]=3$

**Answer:** Let $f(x)=x^3+1 $ be a polynomial in $\mathbb F_{11}[x]$ with $deg(f)=3$. This is also an irreduible in $\mathbb F_{11}$, so $$E=\mathbb F_{11}[x]/(f)$$ is a field extension with $[E:\mathbb F_{11}]=deg(f)=3$.

Do you agree?

Comment: The polynomial $x^3+1$ is not irreducible over $\Bbb{F}_{11}$, since $10^3+1\equiv 0 (\mod 11)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^3+a$ with $a \in \mathbb F_{11}$ is always reducible because $x \mapsto x^3$ is a bijection in $\mathbb F_{11}^\times$ since $\gcd(3,10)=1$.

$x^3+x^2+2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb F_{11}$.

Comment: How did come to that result so fast?

Comment: @serge, trial and error with [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+x%5E3%2Bx%5E2%2B2+mod+11). If you want to know all cubic irreducible polynomials mod $11$, ask [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+x%5E%7B11%5E3%7D-x+mod+11).

Comment: Thanks! It wasn't easy for me to find such an irreducible, since $p$ and $deg$ are big

Comment: Note that $E$ is the splitting field of $x^{11^3}-x$ mod $11$, but factoring $x^{11^3}-x$ is a lot of work: it has $10$ linear factors and $440$ cubic factors.

Answer (score 0):

What about $\Bbb{F}_{11^3}\approx \Bbb{F}_{11}^3$ the isomorphism being an $\Bbb{F}_{11}$-algebra isomorphism. The uniqueness up to (field) isomorphism of a finite field of cardinal $p^q$ shows that $\forall P$ irreducible in $\Bbb{F}_{11}[X]$ of degree $3$

$$\Bbb{F}_{11}[X]/(P)\approx \Bbb{F}_{11^3}$$